# SubmitChanges() throws internal server error

Tags: c#, linq, insert-update, submitchanges

```
public void RejectOrder(string rejectReason, int selectedNewOrderId)
    {
        SFNewOrder sfNewOrder = mdbDataContext.SFNewOrders.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == selectedNewOrderId && !x.IsRejected);

        if (sfNewOrder != null)
        {
            sfNewOrder.IsRejected = true;                              
        }

        SFReject sfReject = new SFReject();

        sfReject.SFNewOrderID = sfNewOrder.ID;
        sfReject.RejectReason = rejectReason;
        sfReject.RejectedDate = DateTime.Now;           
        sfReject.RejectedBy = 2;

        mdbDataContext.SFRejects.InsertOnSubmit(sfReject);
        mdbDataContext.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

Here I want to change `IsRejected` property in `SFNewOrder` Table & Insert a new record In SFReject Table. But I m getting

> internal server error

...on

```
mdbDataContext.submitchanges();
```

Please help... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Internal server error means that something went wrong on the server. Probably some kind of exception raised which you are not aware of. Try to debug to see what kind of exception you get, and then update your question.

Comment: please show  proper error message.

Comment: Add try catch to this block of code, and log the error. or place a break point inside the catch block. Then post the error message here.

Comment: Thanks for advice :) Actually i forgot to use try catch block.
Error is :
"Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'SFReject' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."

Comment: Apologies for my mistake can any one suggest proper solution.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void RejectOrder(string rejectReason, int selectedNewOrderId, User user)
{
    SFNewOrder sfNewOrder = mdbDataContext.SFNewOrders.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == selectedNewOrderId && !x.IsRejected);

    if (sfNewOrder != null)
    {
        sfNewOrder.IsRejected = true;                              
    }

    SFReject sfReject = new SFReject();

    sfReject.SFNewOrder = sfNewOrder; 
    sfReject.RejectReason = rejectReason;
    sfReject.RejectedDate = DateTime.Now;           
    sfReject.User= user;

    mdbDataContext.SFRejects.InsertOnSubmit(sfReject);
    mdbDataContext.SubmitChanges();
}
```

As I have 2 foreign keys in SFReject table I need to assign whole object of that tables.
Its working :)

Comment: I have to say that this was a very confusing error message thrown by the provider.